# count down timer

Tags: java

I would like to execute my `beginrecording()` method after countdown timer gets end. But both methods are executing at same time. can anyone help me to solve this.
my code is follows here:

```
StartBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view)
            { 
                //setContentView(textState);

                MyCount counter = new MyCount(6000, 1000, textState);


                StartBtn.setVisibility(4);
                counter.start();            


                    try
                    {
                    //  Thread.sleep(2000);
                        beginRecording();
                        EndBtn.setVisibility(0);

                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }                               
            }

        });
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

What is `MyCount`? Is it a `Timer`?

May be you should try something like this

```
int i = 0;
Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    if (i == 100){   //-------- When you want to stop timer and start your function
       timer.stop();
       try{
           //  Thread.sleep(2000);
           beginRecording();
           EndBtn.setVisibility(0);
       } catch(Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();
       }    
    } 
    i = i + 1;
   }
});

timer.start();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: MyCount is a class not a timer.
I want to flash five numbers like 5,4,3,2,1 one after one before starting beginRecording() method.

Comment: @Shekhar: maintain it in else part of `if(i==100)`.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that MyCounter's counter object is a subclass of Thread.
So you can call:

counter.join();

before you call

beginRecording();

This ensure that the execution of your counter is over before it returns to the current thread.